# Feedback to achieve four column to column list using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I'm having trouble achieving achieving the a responsive flex layout to house an unordered list. Right now, it is set at two column for large breakpoints and moves to one column at small mobile sizes. I'd like it to be four columns at desktop, laptop and tablet sizes then break to two columns at mobile.

I need to use a unordered list for accessibility purposes as this will eventually hold a list of images, plus it's respective link.

https://codepen.io/shannonhc/pen/WNjjoKp

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row section-header">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <h2 class="section-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="m-list-flex">
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item h-center-items h-flex-columns">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="" />
            <a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```css
div {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.m-list-flex {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.m-list-flex .h-flex-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.m-list-flex .h-center-items {
    text-align: center;
}

.m-list-flex .flex-item {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 600px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {

    .m-list-flex .h-flex-columns,
    .m-list-flex .flex-item {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33%;
        flex-basis: 33%;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 6rem;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a little bit to make it easier to work with.
I created this basic [pen](https://codepen.io/mivoe13xy0/pen/WNjjRPg) and hopefully this is what you meant.

I simplified the class naming scheme. You can change it back to your naming scheme if you want to.

When working with media queries I find it easier to define a default state (in this case the mobile version with only two columns) and then define a query to override that style.

```
ul.flex-list {
    width: calc((200px + 2 * 10px)*2);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
    ul.flex-list {
        width: calc((200px + 2 * 10px)*4);
    }
}
```

The breakpoint can be set to the size you want it to be.
I hope this answers your question. If you have any follow up questions feel free to ask.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and so much cleaner. Thanks! I'm unfamiliar with the width you used in the media query but will do some research on that later.

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't work when I replace the paragraph elements with links. The links run inline with image, creating a one to two column layout depending on how long the text is.  Any suggestions to get the images to sit over links?

Comment: @ShannonH I updated the pen and now it works with a tags.

You can just add a rule for `a` tags with `display` block. Then they display the same way as the `p` elements.

The `calc()` function is a css function and you can use it to calculate the corresponding value. You can even use it to calculate relative values (like %, vh, vw,...) and fixed values (px,...) in one expression. It can be quite useful sometimes but could be omitted here and replaced with just the standard `width: 880px`. Learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc%28%29)